# Django 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and i am having trouble on how to configure this error, so that is why i decided to post a question of some of my code, i hope you guys help me on this problem. did i miss or i did wrong in my code? please bear with me. thanks.

Error `'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'`

Traceback:

> Traceback:
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
> in inner
> 34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in _get_response
> 115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in _get_response
> 113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/unidaweb/unidaproject/Homepage/views.py" in updateperiod
> 2289.             V_insert_data.save()
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
> save
> 741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
> save_base
> 779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
> _save_table
> 870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
> _do_insert
> 908.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py"
> in manager_method
> 82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
> _insert
> 1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in execute_sql
> 1334.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in as_sql
> 1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in 
> 1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in 
> 1277.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>
> File
> "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
> in prepare_value
> 1208.             if value.contains_column_references:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /updateperiod/ Exception Value:
> 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'

this is my views.py

```
id = request.POST.get('id')

if StudentPeriodSummary.objects.filter(id = id).exists():
    grade = request.POST.get('average')
    update = StudentPeriodSummary.objects.get(id = id)
    update.average = grade
    update.save()
    return render(request, 'Homepage/pending.html')
else:
    myperiod = request.POST.get('period')
    period = gradingPeriod(id=myperiod)
    sectionandgrade = request.POST.get('subjectsection')
    gradesSection = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(id=sectionandgrade).values('Sections')
    getsection = Section(id=gradesSection)
    gradeslevel = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(id=sectionandgrade).values('Education_Levels')
    grade = EducationLevel(id=gradeslevel)
    teacher_id = request.POST.get('teacher')

    teacher = EmployeeUser(id=teacher_id)
    averages = []
    for average in request.POST.getlist('average'):
        averages.append(average)
    for m, student in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('studentname')):
        students = StudentSubjectGrade(id=student)
        V_insert_data = StudentPeriodSummary(
            teacher=teacher,
            students_Enrollment_Records=students,
            gradeLevel=grade,
            average=averages[m],
            grading_Period=period,
            sections=getsection,
        )
        V_insert_data.save()
        m += 1

    return render(request, 'Homepage/pending.html')
```

my models.py

```
class StudentPeriodSummary(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, null=True, blank=True)
    students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentSubjectGrade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    gradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel,null=True, blank=True)
    sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, null=True)

    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, null=True, blank=True)
    average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Students_Enrollment_Records}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

**UPDATE**

when i tried to comment out the `#GradeLevel=grade,` and `#Sections=getsection,` in views.py (Inserting data). it works. it seems like from that line is causing the error, what should i do to fix this? is this correct?

```
    gradesSection = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(id=sectionandgrade).values('Sections')
    getsection = Section(id=gradesSection)
    gradeslevel = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(id=sectionandgrade).values('Education_Levels')
    grade = EducationLevel(id=gradeslevel)
```

Comment: where i can find `contains_column_references` ? do i have to show my models.py?

Comment: please show your models.py

Comment: done @ha-neul..

Comment: @ha-neul i hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace:

```
teacher = EmployeeUser(id=teacher_id)
```

with

```
teacher = get_object_or_404(EmployeeUser, id=teacher_id)
```

same thing with

```
getsection = Section(id=gradesSection)
```

`EmpolyeeUser` and `Section` are objects, you need to use `get` or `filter` to get object.

In addition:

```
gradesSection = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(id=sectionandgrade).values('Sections')
getsection = Section(id=gradesSection)
```

Here, the first line, you are using `values` to get `values`. This is not a single value. Therefore you cannot pass it to `id=gradesSection`.

Comment: `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.` i encountered this error

Comment: Please post all your models